# how to put windows back on

Tags: windows-8

i wanted to install ubuntu and windows alongside but I accidently installed Ubuntu 13.10 using the option "LVM" although i've not selected erase disk and fresh install. Now my systems boots direclt into Ubuntu and I'm unable to see my Windows files on hard drive so I'm unable to access my old data (documents, movies, music, pictures) stored on Windows 8? Can someone help me to bring back my old Windows?

Comment: This is a sensible question - why was it down-voted?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Please explain how you intalled Ubuntu - on which partition, or did you use the entire disk, etc.

Comment: At the very minimum, launch `gparted` and paste a snapshot of what you have on your disk(s). Without knowing what exactly you did in the installation it is almost impossible to help you. On the other hand, you surely made a backup before doing something so potentially dangerous as installing another OS, don't you?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what went wrong. But you had to pick an partition to install ubuntu as second operating system. Retrieving the files from the windows drive should be possible. But you will have to re-install windows, if you still want it. Be carefull when you do this 'cause you will have to look out for not deleting the ubuntu files.

Maybe you have luck if windows installer finds the existing files.

To retrieve the files you have to go the filemanager under devices should stand your harddrive under or above computer. When you click you should be possible to see ALL files on your previously installed windows drive.

I hope I helped you out here!

Comment: Reinstalling windows without knowing what has happened before is a good path to really losing all files.

Comment: Dude downvote? Did you even read the question and my answer on it... 

That's what I meant in my answer too.

Comment: Yes --- because I think that you suggested a very dangerous thing. If he used LVM and choose the windows 8 partition by error, he has a (tiny) chance of recovering by using some recovery tool. If he reinstall windows 8, it will not recognise the partition type and wipe it clean, and that will be it. So see? Anyway, if I am wrong and you are right, your answer will be upvoted by others --- is how this site works, so do not worry.